# Do I need to go through my payroll and enter the taxes for each quarter here? 1040, H&R

Tags: taxes

I've entered my W2, 1099-B, 1099-SA, 1099-DIV, etc. on H&R Block. Now I'm seeing this:

[image: My H&R screen]

I'm in a state of ambiguity, because what are the W2's and 1099's for if I need to "estimate" here?

Because I saw "FORM 1040" on the top left, I looked it up. [The 1040 wiki's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_1040) kind of overwhelming, and looking on the IRS site didn't disambiguate this.

Can someone outline of what it's asking of me here? Do I need to go back through my payroll, add up the taxes for each month, and put it in here? (Imo this doesn't seem right).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Estimated* tax payments](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/heres-how-and-when-to-pay-estimated-taxes) do not include taxes *withheld* (e.g., on W-2). If you made quarterly *estimated* payments in 2020, enter them here. If not, leave it blank (or correct any previous mistake that led you to this screen). You were not required to make estimated payments if your withholding met the "safe harbor" (typically 90% of your tax owed).